# Join two tables on ID where table one has duplicates and table two does not

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have two tables, Table A['id', 'col1'] and Table B['id', 'col3']. Table A has duplicate values in 'id' column and its important that those duplicate row stay as they are but Table B has single pair for 'id' and 'col3'. I want to use python to join the two tables.

Table A

| id | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 1 | Mango |
| 2 | Banana |

Table B

| id | col3 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Eat |
| 2 | Drink |

Final output

| id | col1 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Eat |
| 1 | Mango | Eat |
| 2 | Banana | Drink |

I tried to use merge and concat but did not get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to use `merge` to do it:

```py
A.merge(B, how='left') )
```

Explanation:

- In the docs for [`merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), when the `how` argument is `'left'`:

  - use only keys from left frame, similar to a SQL left outer join; **preserve key order**.
- Also from the docs, when the `on` argument is not specified, it takes the default value of None, and `on` is interpreted as follows:

  - Column or index level names to join on. These must be found in both DataFrames. **If on is None and not merging on indexes then this defaults to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames**.

Output:

```
   id    col1   col3
0   1   Apple    Eat
1   1   Mango    Eat
2   2  Banana  Drink
```

Comment: Appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
tableA = tableA.merge(right=tableB, how='left', on='id')
```